# Lesk nltk optimize search

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

I have a code that works perfectly but it's take to much time to execute, here is the code:

```
result_lesk=[]
result=[]
for i in range (0,len(texto_palabras)):
  result_lesk.append(lesk(texto_palabras,texto_palabras[i]))
print(result_lesk)

print (len(result_lesk))
print(len(result))


for i in range(0,len(result_lesk)):
 if(result_lesk[i] is not None):
  result.append(result_lesk[i])
print(result)  

result=set(result)
result=list(result)
print(result)

for i in range(0,len(result)):
  for synset in wn.all_synsets():
    if(result[i]==synset):
      best_synset_lemma_names=synset.lemma_names()



len_best_synset_lemma_names=len(best_synset_lemma_names)
for i in range(0,len(best_synset_lemma_names)):
  texto_palabras.append(best_synset_lemma_names[i])
```

In short words, I have a text and this i need to disambiguate, then for every synset (lesk result) , I have to search the lemmas names ( synonyms) for adding in other process .
The problem is the lesk result is only a string, and I need the synset with the wn.synset.lemma_names()
Any idea how I optimize ?
Thanks!!

Comment: I forgot to say, the search over all wordnet synsets takes the time :)

Comment: Can you explain the question clearer? Isolate the part of the code that needs help.

Comment: BTW, have you tried https://github.com/alvations/pywsd ? (Disclaimer: shameless plug)